# Load dynamic library functions (C++)

Tags: c++, function, libraries, shared

On another question ([Can I have a dynamic library required only when used by the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051729/can-i-have-a-dynamic-library-required-only-when-used-by-the-code)) I have noticed that it is possible to load functions from a shared library only when required to. But how does the name get found? On disassembled objects I can see that the function names such as `_ZN5Foo3barEv`so how does the program know how to find that? Also for overloaded functions they have slightly different names so how would you load 1 of those overloaded functions?

I have tried some basic research but I have not really found anything on this matter

Comment: You seem to be asking about [name mangling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314743/what-is-name-mangling-and-how-does-it-work#:~:text=Name%20mangling%20solves%20the%20problem,with%20more%20than%20one%20meaning.).  `_ZN5Foo3barEv` is a mangled symbol name, that accounts for overloading.

Comment: If this is Windows, the command line tool DUMPBIN /DEPENDENTS will reveal the exported functions and their respective names and ordinals.

Comment: Ah but how would you load a specific function that is name mangled if you only know what the programmer called the function?

Comment: @TheDuck from the documentation. Or if the program has provided it, a header files of names and function definitions.  It's also much easier with a pure `C` interface. With a `C++` interface you also need to check for ABI compatability.

Comment: Use pimpl. Define an abstract class. Extend it in dynamic library. Call a `get` 
wiht C linkage function from the dynamic library returning a pointer to the interface. You can also call a function returning a pointer to a tuple of functions. Who needs names?

Comment: @RichardCritten ah so its much more complicated than just loading it. But what is ABI?